# TabControl - catch the tab activated event

Tags: .net, winforms

I am using Windows.Forms and .Net 2.0.

In Windows TabControl; how can I catch the event that fires anytime the user switches to a tab.

For example; If i have a tabControl with 4 tab pages; I would like to call a function anytime the user switches to a tab.

Comment: Did you try to check which events are exposed by the TabControl in Visual Studio? you will see the SelectedTabChanged or TabSelected events, something like that... use one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selected.aspx